# regular expression for pair of letters in the same word

Tags: regex, grep

I need to find all the words which has the same occurrence of pair of letters at least twice (word is all non white space characters between spaces, ie chochol , 9933499 ). I came up with this regex however its not working and i cant figure out how to write it properly.

```
[ ]\S*(\S\S)\S*\1\S*[ ]
```

Comment: You need a regex that will match a word that has a certain letter 2 or more times?

Comment: Try `grep -oP '\S*(\S\S)\S*\1\S*'`

Comment: word that has certain pair of letters (two letters) repeating in itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[ ]` in your pattern are redundant and even harmful since they prevent from matching overlapping (subsequent, after 1 space) substrings.

You need to use

```
grep -oP '\S*(\S\S)\S*\1\S*'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/zaZp84)

If you only need to match "words" with two repeated identical consecutive *letters*, replace `(\S\S)` with `([A-Za-z]{2})` or even `\p{L}{2}`.

Comment: No they are not identical, its a pair of letters - 2 letters, ie hooffooted, 12345347. And word is very specific, its everything between two spaces, except whitespace characters, so it could be even something like ti:/g:/er